# Geodesics from a Lagrangian in a restricted space

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, variational-principle, geodesics

Given a certain action (for instance),
\begin{equation}
    S = \int_\alpha^\beta d\lambda ~ L(\dot x, x, \lambda)
\end{equation}
where $\lambda$ is some affine parameter.

In order to minimise it, we compute the Euler-Lagrange equations. But what if the pace where $t$ and $x$ live is restricted? Say $(x,t)\in A$, where $A$ is a certain domain. How can we restrict the geodesics to be only in $A$?

Comment: By excluding stationary paths that are not fully inside the $A$ region?

Comment: @Qmechanic Then if a geodesic between a and b goes outside the region at some point, can we still find some shorter path between a and b that sits inside the region $A$?

Comment: Be aware that an optimal path may touch the boundary of $A$ and not be stationary.

Comment: @Qmechanic I see your point. So I should just exclude these solution and say that there is no geodesic between those two points? btw (if it helps), the geodesic I am looking for are spacelike (at constant time)